# Installing .gem and its dependencies offline

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems

I am trying to install a plugin `.gem` file (`logstash-output-apm-Release-APM-10.5.1-DxC-1.4-20170114.212431-8.gem`), supplied by the vendor, but it failed with the error below, as I'm running the `install` command from a machine with NO Internet access:

```
[user@server_hostname bin]$ ./logstash-plugin install DigitalExperienceCollector-Release-APM-10.5.1-DxC-1.4-SNAPSHOT-2017_01_14_13_24/logstash/apm-logstash-plugin/logstash-output-apm-Release-APM-10.5.1-DxC-1.4-20170114.212431-8.gem

Validating DigitalExperienceCollector-Release-APM-10.5.1-DxC-1.4-SNAPSHOT-2017_01_14_13_24/logstash/apm-logstash-plugin/logstash-output-apm-Release-APM-10.5.1-DxC-1.4-20170114.212431-8.gem
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/
- Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - Connection refused (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Is there a way to download the `latest_specs.4.8.gz` manually, and supply to the `.gem` file without modifying the `.gem` file?
Or will the vendor need to make some modification on the `.gem` file to load from a local copy?

Answer (score 0):

You can install a gem locally by using the `--local` flag from the directory containing the gem.

For example, to install a `my_gem-0.1.0.gem` I downloaded previously to my `/downloads/gems/` directory:

```
$ cd downloads/gems
$ gem install my_gem --local
```

**The downside being that you still won't be able to fetch any of the `runtime_dependency` gems.**

Answer (score 0):

You should build and "offline plugin pack"
It will include dependencies
so that you will be able to install it offline.

Details [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/offline-plugins.html)

`bin/logstash-plugin prepare-offline-pack --output OUTPUT --overwrite [PLUGINS]`

- OUTPUT specifies the zip file where the compressed plugin pack will be written. The default file is /LOGSTASH_HOME/logstash-offline-plugins-8.0.1.zip. If you are using 5.2.x and 5.3.0, this location should be a zip file whose contents will be overwritten.
- [PLUGINS] specifies one or more plugins that you want to include in the pack.
- --overwrite specifies if you want to override an existing file at the location

then on the target machine:

`bin/logstash-plugin install file:///path/to/logstash-offline-plugins-8.0.1.zip`